# How to plot the likelihood for the location parameter of the Cauchy distribution with a given dataset

Tags: data-visualization, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to plot the likelihood function of $\theta$ for the $\text{Cauchy}(\theta,1)$ distribution given a specific data set. I am using the code below and it doesn΄t work.

```
data    <- read.table("mydata", head=F)
theta   <- seq(1, 3, l=100)
density <- function(theta) { prod( dcauchy(data, theta, 1) ) }
plot(theta, density(theta), type="l", xlab="theta",
            main="Likelihood function", col="blue")
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Don't call your data, "data".

Comment: Also it's better when supplying code if you also supply an example data set (it doesn't have to be your 'real' data, as long as it has the same problem), so that your code runs. That is, you should supply an example that we can run by copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

`theta` has 100 values, while `density(theta)` has 1, so `plot` produces the error message

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

You need something else inside the curly braces.  The following works, though there will be prettier ways

```
density <- function(theta){ exp(colSums(outer(data, theta, 
                            function(x,y){ dcauchy(x, y, 1, log=TRUE) } ))) }
```